# Can I use Spring without annotations at all only through xmls?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, annotations

I have a web application using spring annotations extensively. Can I switch back from spring annotations to xml configuration files? Encluding controllers,..etc. I need examples of the configuration files please.

Comment: <bean class="a.b.c.MyClass" />
rinse, repeat

Comment: Why switch from annotations?  Is your code too readable?

Comment: It is mostly doable but keep in mind you would have to change your spring-mvc code to inherit from spring classes/interfaces to get rid of annotations.

Comment: Can you please give examples? I need on controllers, requests, services,..etc.

Comment: There are plenty of examples...seek and ye shall find.

Comment: I think you need to look into documentation for version 2.5. Non-annotations spring-MVC api is considered old-way and could be deprecated some time in the future. Link here: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/mvc.html#mvc-controller

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you can switch to externalize the configuration using xml's. Initially only xml's were supported by spring. You can get examples from their [reference manual](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/reference/htmlsingle/).

If you are looking for complete examples then [www.springbyexample.org](http://www.springbyexample.org/)

Comment: I can see a lot of annotations everywhere, where precisely it's referenced with examples that deal with the application without annotations?

Comment: @Harout what do you mean? I see lot of xml examples. Look at " Examples of dependency injection" section

Comment: @Harout,  annotations are preferred over large xml configuration files...that's why most examples use annotations.

Comment: @Paul OK, I'm with you but I need to switch back for some other purposes.

Answer (score 4):

Yes.  Spring supports annotations, configuration classes and xml configuration. It was never the goal of annotations to deprecate the xml configuration, and it is still fully supported today.

At the S2G forum in Amsterdam last year, it was specifically stated that the goal remains for both approaches to be completely equivalent.

As for the details on how to do it, the documentation of Spring is very good.  I suggest you start there.  Check out the [pet store example](https://src.springframework.org/svn/spring-samples/jpetstore/trunk/org.springframework.samples.jpetstore/src/), and read up on ContextLoaderListener.  It should get you started.

Comment: Can you give some hints on how to achieve this, because the documentaion includes lots of lots of info! whew! –

Comment: @Harout that would mean we'd have to give a full Spring course, right here :)  I added some text on a good place to get started.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can switch back and forth to XML and annotations.  In fact, if you even need, you can use a combination of both.  Additionally, depending on the type of control you are trying to extract from XML configuration, you can also use [@Configuration](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-java) annotations which provides a way of producing XML configuration via Java code.  Keep in mind, however, that there are a few obscure configuration constructs that are not representable by any annotations and can only be done via XML files.

Comment: OK, but can you please give examples that can direct me to that? the xml and code?

Comment: Did you click on the link?  It links to the Spring docs. http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-java